# Getting most common value within a query

Tags: sql

I have table where users perform an action that has several different options. I want figure out

1. which 100 users have performed the most actions
2. for each of the 100 users, what
       the most common option of action performed was

So far, I have the first part figured out:

```
select a.user_id, count(a.id)
from actions a
group by a.user_id
having count(*) > 1
order by count(a.id) desc
limit 100
```

This gives me the 100 most active users. How can I modify this to get the most common different `type` of action?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: Select only `Group By [actionName]` - just group by whatever the column name is for the action name or type and it will give you a list of different action types with count

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `type` is your action and using a language similar to yours:

```
Select au.user_id, au.total_actions, at.type, at.nb_of_type

From        ( select user_id, count(id) as total_actions
              from actions
              group by type
              having count(*) > 1
              order by count(id) desc
              limit 100 ) As au -- ActiveUser

Inner join  ( select user_id, type, MAX(count(a.id)) as nb_of_type
              from action
              group by user_id, type ) As at -- ActiveType

On at.user_id = au.user_id
```

Assuming you're in SQL Server with a correct syntax and a better efficiency :

```
WITH ActiveUser (user_id, total_actions)
AS
(
    select top 100 user_id, count(id)
    from actions 
    group by type
    order by count(id) desc
)

Select au.user_id, au.nb_total_of_actions, t.type, t.nb_of_type
From  ActiveUser au
Inner join  ( select user_id, type, MAX(count(id)) as nb_of_type
              from action
              group by user_id, type
              where user_id in (Select user_id from ActiveUser) 
            ) at -- ActiveType
On at.user_id = au.user_id
```